# go from app requirement throw choosing between cross platform or native

Tags: android, ios, titanium, cross-platform, titanium-mobile

I know this question is maybe duplicate but the other question even are outdated or not like what i want to know  e.g all comparing native(ios,java) with html based cross platform (like comparing CSS3 capabilities in the design or jquery mobile with native languages)
**NOTE** i want to compare between native cross platform like titanium or xamarin and native ios or java i'm not into html based cross platform
so my question is that if i have a mobile app requirement and i want to choose wither to use native or cross platform (mostly) to develop this app
**Firstly:** many people saying that you shouldn't use Cross Platform if you have a complex app
so how i can say that app is complex or not to choose between both
**secondly:** what is the requirement or feature which will take me away from cross platform if i want to include it in my app (e.g animation)
**Thirdly:** as many said that cross platform is not recommended when my app has to access to hardware component of the device but in my case titanium or xamarin will give me a native app  and both have an API to access native feature in iOS or android at least so why they differ from the native iOS,android app in performance and memory management
Thanks in advance

Comment: Everything depends on how much work you can put into it.  It's not a linear jump to multiple platforms, more like a quadratic one.  3 platforms will be at least 10 times more complex, no matter what framework you use (but especially if you use an HTML or Javascript based one) unless your app consists of a very simple workflow.

Comment: you should read these blogs to get a proper idea : [blog1](http://www.codenutz.com/ultimate-cross-platform-mobile-development-guide-part-2/), [blog2](http://www.gotechark.com/choosing-best-mobile-app-development-platform/), [blog3](http://tech.pro/blog/1355/when-to-go-native-mobile-web-or-cross-platformhybrid)